# Memory consumption with UIImageView in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, memory-leaks, uiimage

I am developing an app that loads images from the folder only (not from any web server).

It's working pretty perfectly but I am worried about memory consumption by UITableView.

Whenever I scroll UITableView, ***memory is allocated and never deallocated***.
I am using release on all objects.

Please see my code below.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"OtherThingsName"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"OtherThingsName"];
    }

    if ([cell viewWithTag:123]!=nil) {
        NSLog(@"Removed");
        [[cell viewWithTag:123] removeFromSuperview];
        [[cell viewWithTag:1231] removeFromSuperview];
        [[cell viewWithTag:1232] removeFromSuperview];
    }

    UIView *viewInTableCell=nil;
    UILabel *lblTitleInCell=nil;
    UIImageView *imageInCell=nil;

    viewInTableCell = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
    lblTitleInCell = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, (cell.bounds.size.height/2), 190, 30)];
    imageInCell = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 80)];

    [lblTitleInCell setText:[self.arrayOfOtherThings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [imageInCell setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[self.arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

    [viewInTableCell setTag:123];
    [lblTitleInCell setTag:1231];
    [imageInCell setTag:1232];

    [viewInTableCell addSubview:lblTitleInCell];
    [viewInTableCell addSubview:imageInCell];

    [cell addSubview:viewInTableCell];

    //    cell.textLabel.text = [self.arrayOfOtherThings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    lblTitleInCell = nil;
    imageInCell = nil;
    viewInTableCell = nil;

    [lblTitleInCell release];
    [imageInCell release];
    [viewInTableCell release];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Please find a good `UITableView` tutorial and start from there. What you are doing is wrong. You are adding the same subviews to the cell over and over again when it comes visible on the screen.

Comment: thanks for reply @Desdenova , but i also set them "nil" after using them. So, it does not frees memory in any way ?

Comment: not as you think it would because cell itself holds them. You need to use custom `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Ok thanks.. i found a tutorial.. @Desdenova